# NetworkManager.service error

Tags: kali-linux

when i run service NetworkManager restart i get

```
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xeu NetworkManager.service" for details
```

can't seem to find a solution by myself

it says that start request repeated too quickly and failed to start